# Python Code Error 3.3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback

I have recently been practicing my skills at figuring out my own problems but this one problem is persistent. This is the problematic code:

```
with open('login_names.txt', 'r') as f:
        login_name = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
        k = input("name: ")
        if k in login_name :
            print("No errors")
        else:
            print("You have an error")
else:
    print('fail')
#var = login_name.index[random]
check = login_pass[login_name.index[random]]


with open('login_passw.txt', 'r') as p:
    login_pass = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in p]
    s = input("pass: ")
    if s == check :
        print("Works")
    else:
        print("Doesn't work")

f.close()
p.close()
```

Basically when I run the code it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/Test.py", line 29, in <module>
    check = login_pass[login_name.index[random]]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried lots of different suggestions on different questions but none of them have worked for me...

Comment: What exactly is that line of code supposed to do?

Comment: What is the line `login_pass[login_name.index[random]]` supposed to do?  Do you have the types available?  The error message says that either `login_pass` or `login_name.index` doesn't support index, which you're using on both.  Unfortunately, your error message does not provide enough information to determine which.  If `login_name` is a `list`, then you should have `login_name.index(random)`, since that would be the method `index` on lists.

Comment: `login_name.index[random]` should probably be `login_name.index(random)`, but it seems like `login_pass` is not defined yet at this point in the code...

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that `login_pass`, `login_name` and `random` are defined in the namespace that line is in, the only problem you have is that you should write

```
check = login_pass[login_name.index(random)]
```

`str.index` is a **function** that returns the first index of the argument given in `str`, so you use `()` instead of `[]`, which you would use for lists, tuples and dictionaries.